# Identify EditText Input Source

Tags: android

Is it possible to identify the input source of the text in an EditText as it changes? ie. Is the text from the soft keyboard or from a hardware keyboard?

I have a customer using bluetooth barcode scanners (which are effectively a hardware keyboard) and they want to identify which transactions occur as a result of a barcode scan and which occur because of typed input.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to determine this.

Comment: have you got the solution for this? want to implement similar thing.